# How to reassign uid:gid to all users and automatically fix all file ownerships and permissions?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, file-permissions, multiple-users

I want to reassign new uid:gid to all existing users and automatically fix all file ownerships and permission.

The user names will stay the same just the uids and gids will be updated.

How can I update/reassign uids:gids and take care of permissions and ownerships in the process?

I want to update `user1`, `user2`, and `user3` as per following file,

```
user1:user1:1000:1000:User Name 1:/data/home/user1:/bin/bash
user2:user2:1001:1001:User Name 2:/data/home/user2:/bin/bash
user3:user3:1002:1002:User Name 3:/data/home/user3:/bin/bash
```

> Note: `user1`, `user2` and 'user3' already exist but with different `uid:gid`. Also, All users are currently members of a group named `members` with `gid` 1008. I would also like to update the `gid`
> of `members` group and keep them in the updated `members` group.

> Note: None of them is a user with `sudo` privileges.

I changed the `gid` of `members` from `1008` to `2000`. and the `uid:gid` of each user as shown above but now shared directories and some shared programs for example, `conda` on `/shared/anaconda` is not working for some users. `Permission denied

Also, some users are unable to access their `home` directory.
I am looking for a stable reliable solution that can migrate all permissions from old users to new users.

Comment: What is the point? Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is.

Comment: I have updated the question. This is not an XY problem. I am just looking for a solution to my problem.

Comment: (1) UID is just a number. What difference does it make *for you* if it's `1005` or `1000`? There are valid reasons for a change; e.g. you may want to have the same UIDs across two or more systems. Is this your reason? (2) Are the new UIDs or GIDs already taken? (3) It may help if you tell us the existing UIDs and GIDs for the users/groups in question (4) "I would also like to update the gid of `members` group and keep them in the updated `members` group" -- update from what value to what value? (5) We expect questions to show research effort. Have you found any lead? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes I have 2 more systems and I want to have same uids:gids across all of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to do this for all users and groups that you wish to
change, one user/group after the other.

Assuming a user-name `Foo` UID:1005, and group `foo` with GID:2000,
and you're renaming to new UID:2005 and new GID:3000.

To assign a new UID to user foo :

```
usermod -u 2005 foo
```

To assign a new GID to group foo :

```
groupmod -g 3000 foo
```

Verify that you changed UID and GID for given users with the
ls command:

```
ls -l
```

Files in the user’s home directory should be automatically fixed
after the above two commands.

For files outside the user’s home directory use the following with great
care:

```
find / -group 2000 -exec chgrp -h foo {} \;
find / -user 1005 -exec chown -h foo {} \;
```

The -h option will work on symbolic links instead of their referenced files.

Use these commands to verify the operation:

```
ls -l /home/foo/
id -u foo
id -g foo
# search for 'foo' in the passswd file #
grep foo /etc/passwd # search for 'foo' in the group file #
grep foo /etc/group # use the find command to locate files owned by ' foo'#
find / -user foo -ls
find / -group sales -ls
```

Reference :
[How to Change a USER and GROUP ID on Linux For All Owned Files](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-change-user-group-uid-gid-for-all-owned-files/)

Comment: In my case, the current `gid` of group `members` is 1008 which is now being assigned to `user8`. All users including `user8` belong to the group `members`

Comment: So there is no automatic way where I can just supply a text file having all users with new uid gid?

Comment: You will need to write a bash script for it.

Comment: Thank you. As my question is to find a way to automatically do this, and your answer is manual. I will use this to write a bash script, and if it works, I will upvote your answer.

Comment: FYI: We're not a script-writing site, so any post asking to write a script would surely be closed.

Comment: I am just saying that I am looking for something to do automatically, and I will wait sometime to mark it as an acceptable answer. This surely helps in solving the problem.