# How to sync UIDs and GIDs across multiple machines with minimal impact on users' experience?

Tags: nfs, cluster, slurm

I have two workstations, WS 1 and WS 2, and a server, S, all running Ubuntu 22.04. These machines were previously managed independently, so users could have accounts on some or all of them, and different groups exist on them.

I would like to set up a cluster with the machines to enable submitting slurm jobs to them based on their available resources. I created an `/nfs` directory and set up an NFS server on S, and installed NFS clients on WSs and mounted `/nfs` on them.

I see in [Slurm's quick start guide](https://slurm.schedmd.com/quickstart_admin.html) that clocks, UIDs, and GIDs should be synced across all devices. How can I achieve this with as little impact on users as possible?

I see a few problems that need to be addressed:

1. Using FreeIPA or some other tools for managing logins. Please let me know if you have any suggestions because I have not used any such tools in the past.
2. Synchronizing UIDs and GIDs without users losing access to their data.
3. While S is supposed to be the entry system for Slurm, users should be able to log in to WSs directly.
4. Synchronizing/Merging users' home directories. Although I do not know if this is an absolute must.

I would appreciate it if you could help me with this problem.

Edit 1:
I understand [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1736609/how-to-reassign-uidgid-to-all-users-and-automatically-fix-all-file-ownerships-a) is about a similar issue on a single machine, where the answer helps resolve the issue manually. I am, however, looking to make such changes from a centralized machine like S, and keep track of users and groups on the master machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only step that might have an impact is changing existing UIDs when the same UID on different systems belongs to different users (re-chown'ing their files, etc.) – chown should go mostly unnoticed, but it does require killing *all* of that user's running processes.

The actual migration to a central database can be done in steps, as it's allowed to have the same account both in LDAP *and* in /etc/passwd (whichever is listed first in nsswitch.conf will have priority), so for example you could gradually add accounts to LDAP and remove them from local /etc/passwd one by one.

> Using FreeIPA or some other tools for managing logins. Please let me know if you have any suggestions because I have not used any such tools in the past.

There are two options:

1. Central database (user directory server). In the past it used to mean NIS, these days it's some type of LDAP service – either a complete solution such as FreeIPA or Active Directory, or a manually managed LDAP database such as OpenLDAP or 389-ds. You would typically use either SSSD or nslcd as the system-wide LDAP client (or Winbind for AD).
2. Centrally distributed "local" accounts. Basically, using configuration management tools such as Salt/Ansible/Puppet either to handle account creation or to deploy the entire /etc/passwd file.

Which one to choose depends on preference and various other criteria; e.g. a local /etc/passwd will never go down unlike LDAP, but at the same time doesn't scale well beyond a few hundred users.

Note that authentication is handled separately from user account storage. For password auth, the passwords can be verified against the same LDAP server, or against a Kerberos KDC (FreeIPA), regardless of whether it's a local user or an LDAP user. So you could manage the accounts as local ones via /etc/passwd but set up Kerberos for SSO.

(For SSH keypairs, the sshd service doesn't care much, but can be set up to pull authorized_keys from LDAP or some other arbitrary source rather than looking in ~/.ssh/.)

> Synchronizing UIDs and GIDs without users losing access to their data.

You'll need to handle this by hand, before/during the initial account import into the central list. Gather lists of all local accounts from all systems, search for those with duplicate UIDs, and adjust them to match using `usermod` and `chown -R` (making sure to not create *new* duplicates).

> Synchronizing/Merging users' home directories. Although I do not know if this is an absolute must.

This depends on your needs. You could merge the home directories and mount them from a file server via NFS (possibly using autofs), or you could keep them local and use NFS for non-$HOME data only. (Whether the accounts are local or central doesn't matter, as long as UIDs are in sync.)